# Uncaught TypeError: keyHandler is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm building an MVC style javascript game and I've run into a problem. I need to check if the keyState is 39 before calling a function, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _self.keyHandler is not a function
```

Can anybody help me? The problem is with the following piece of code:

```
    if(keyState[39] = true){
        _self.keyHandler();
    };
```

FULL CODE:

```
GOBLINS.Controller.prototype.input = function() {

        var _self = this;
        var keyState = {};

    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
        if(e.keyCode === 39){ // Move Right
            keyState[e.keyCode] = true; 
        };
        if(e.keyCode === 37){ // Move Left
            keyState[e.keyCode] = true; 
        };
        if(e.keyCode === 38){ // Move Up
            keyState[e.keyCode] = true; 
        };
        if(e.keyCode === 40){ // Move Down
            keyState[e.keyCode] = true; 
        };
    }, true);

    window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 39){
            keyState[e.keyCode] = false; 
        };
        if(e.keyCode == 37){
            keyState[e.keyCode] = false; 
        };
        if(e.keyCode == 38){
            keyState[e.keyCode] = false; 
        };
        if(e.keyCode == 40){
            keyState[e.keyCode] = false; 
        };
    }, true);

        if(keyState[39] = true){
            _self.keyHandler();
        };

    this.keyHandler = function(){
        if(keyState[39] === true){
            this.M.images[2].moveRight();
            console.log(this.M.images[2]);
            };
        if(keyState[37] === true){
            this.M.images[2].moveLeft();
            };
        if(keyState[38] === true){
            this.M.images[2].moveUp();
            };
        if(keyState[40] === true){
            this.M.images[2].moveDown();
        };
    };

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
        _self.input();
    });
};
```

Comment: @SHAZ, please don't add meaningless formatting to the post just to bypass the 6 character rule. It's there exactly so that you don't make too little improvement to the post. In the future, please find something *meaningful* to improve in the post, and suggest that. Otherwise, please don't suggest an edit at all.

Comment: actually you are assigning true to keyState[39] the way you have written it

Comment: how is this prototype linked up with your UI, in other words when is it initiated and when does it get called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `_self.keyHandler()` three lines before assigning it.

You have this block:

```
if(keyState[39] = true){
    _self.keyHandler();
};
```

before this one:

```
this.keyHandler = function(){
    // ...
}
```

when it would have to be the other way round in order to work.

Also, as [Icepickle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3231537/icepickle) pointed out, `keyState[39] = true` is an assignment (and hence always true), so you might want to replace that `=` by `==`.

With functions you could do the following:

```
a();
function a(){}
```

because function declarations are hoisted (moved to the top of the scope in which they are defined).
But for properties, this does not apply, and since `this.keyHandler` is a property, the above does not apply and you get an error.

Comment: isn't the keyState[39] = true an assignment rather than a test if it's true ;)

Comment: Have you heard of hoisting?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha For **functions** yes, but for **properties**? Are you saying the following code should work? `function derp(){this.meow();this.meow = function(){console.log('meow');};}var a = new derp();` because it gives me an error.